# Injecting Functions causes No Firebase App error

Tags: angular, firebase, angularfire

I'm following the instructions from [angular/angularfire sample](https://github.com/angular/angularfire/blob/master/samples/modular/src/app/functions/functions.component.ts), yet I receive an error when I call Functions in my component.

**App module**

```
@NgModule({

  imports:      [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    provideFirebaseApp(() => initializeApp(environment.firebase)),
    provideAuth(() => {
      const auth = getAuth();
      if (!environment.production) connectAuthEmulator(auth, "http://localhost:9099", {disableWarnings: true});
      return auth;
    }),
    provideFirestore(() => {
      const firestore = getFirestore();
      if (!environment.production) connectFirestoreEmulator(firestore, "localhost", 8080);
      return firestore;
    }),
    provideFunctions(() => {
      const functions = getFunctions();
      if (!environment.production) {
        connectFunctionsEmulator(functions, "localhost", 5001);
      }
      return functions;
    })

  ],
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  providers:    [
    provideAnimations(),
    {provide: LOCALE_ID, useValue: "nl-NL"}
  ],
  bootstrap:    [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

**Firebase config**

```
export const environment = {
  firebase:   {
    projectId:         "xxxxxxxxxxxx",
    appId:             "xxxxxxxxxxxx",
    storageBucket:     "xxxxxxxxxxxx",
    apiKey:            "xxxxxxxxxxxx",
    authDomain:        "xxxxxxxxxxxx",
    messagingSenderId: "xxxxxxxxxxxx",
  },
  production: true
};
```

**Component**

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core";
import { Functions } from "@angular/fire/functions";

@Component({
  selector: "app-root",
  template: "<router-outlet></router-outlet>",
  styles:   [""]
})
export class AppComponent {

  constructor(functions: Functions) {}
}
```

**Resulting Error**

```
main.ts:6 ERROR FirebaseError: Firebase: No Firebase App '[DEFAULT]' has been created - call initializeApp() first (app/no-app).
    at getApp (index.esm2017.js:479:29)
    at getFunctions (index.esm2017.js:668:35)
    at angular-fire.js:227:48
    at angular-fire.js:160:59
    at _ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone.js:368:26)
    at Zone.run (zone.js:129:43)
    at NgZone.runOutsideAngular (core.mjs:10917:28)
    at runOutsideAngular (angular-fire.js:160:35)
    at angular-fire.js:227:21
    at app.module.ts:34:37
```

When I can call Auth and Firestore there are no errors. Only when I include Functions in the app.component constructor this error pops up.

I've tried injecting functions with `functions = inject(Functions)` as well as shown in the sample in the constructor.